# How to make Armeria exit on an `Address already in use` error?

Tags: armeria

How do I make sure that my program exits when Armeria fails to start because of an `Address already in use` error?

I have the following code:

```
import com.linecorp.armeria.common.HttpRequest;
import com.linecorp.armeria.common.HttpResponse;
import com.linecorp.armeria.server.AbstractHttpService;
import com.linecorp.armeria.server.Server;
import com.linecorp.armeria.server.ServerBuilder;
import com.linecorp.armeria.server.ServiceRequestContext;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerBuilder sb = Server.builder();
        sb.http(8080);

        sb.service("/greet/{name}", new AbstractHttpService() {
            @Override
            protected HttpResponse doGet(ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
                String name = ctx.pathParam("name");
                return HttpResponse.of("Hello, %s!", name);
            }
        });

        Server server = sb.build();
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = server.start();
        future.join();
    }

}
```

When I run it once everything is fine.
But when I run it the second time I get an `Address already in use` error, which is of course expected, but the program doesn't terminate on its own. This may be how it is supposed to be, but how do I make sure that it terminates upon errors during initialization?

```
$ gradle run

> Task :run
14:36:04.811 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
14:36:04.815 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
14:36:04.816 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 8
14:36:04.817 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
14:36:04.817 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
14:36:04.818 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
...
14:36:05.064 [globalEventExecutor-3-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
14:36:05.068 [globalEventExecutor-3-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
14:36:05.068 [globalEventExecutor-3-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
14:36:05.068 [globalEventExecutor-3-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:953)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:739)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:250)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [6s]
> :run
^C
```

Comment: Sorry for a very late response. I think it's a bug in Armeria. Will send a fix soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Armeria, where Netty event loop threads are not terminated when a `Server` fails to start up. Here's the fix PR, which should be part of the next release (0.97.0): https://github.com/line/armeria/pull/2288